# ¿Cómo usar el paginador de Laravel en un arreglo?

Tags: laravel

En la siguiente consulta, deseo agregar un paginador, hice una búsqueda con Scope, pero, tuve que agregar otras cosas porque si por ejemplo, en la bd estaba escrito "Casa Azul", y en el buscador lo escribía tal cual, me mostraba los resultados, pero si escribía "Azul Casa", no me mostraba nada, debo agregarle un paginador, he intentado algunas cosas, pero el paginador se muestra en la vista pero no me funciona, o se me daña el buscador. He leído que tengo que usar Eloquent, pero al tener una variable en el condicional, no sé como aplicarlo.

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $city1 = $request->get('city1');
    $arr_city1= explode(' ', $city1);
    $direccion = $request->get('direccion');
    $arr_direccion= explode(' ', $direccion);
    $where = '';
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_city1);$i++){
      $where.='city1 LIKE "%'.$arr_city1[$i].'%" AND ';
    }
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_direccion);$i++){
      $where.='direccion LIKE "%'.$arr_direccion[$i].'%" AND ';
    }
    $where = substr($where,0,strlen($where)-4)." ORDER BY id";
    $clientes = DB::select('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE '.$where);

    return view('buscador.index', compact('clientes'));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco confuso lo que pretendes hacer, dado que estás haciendo una especie de *raw query*, la cual además desconocemos totalmente para ayudarte mejor.

En caso que sea necesario hacer un query de la forma como lo estás realizando, la única opción que tendrás sea probablemente la que ya estás usando: `LIMIT x,y`

Para usar el paginador de Laravel no es necesario usar Eloquent, también puedes aplicarlo al Query Builder:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

Puedes revisar la documentación relacionada: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, disculpa si no me hice entender. Hice una búsqueda con Scope, pero, tuve que agregar otras cosas porque si por ejemplo, en la bd estaba escrito "Casa Azul", y en el buscador lo escribía tal cual, me mostraba los resultados, pero si escribía "Azul Casa", no me mostraba nada, entonces,  en resumen, me quedaba la consulta como la describo en $clientes, pero quiero agregarle un paginador, he intentado algunas cosas, pero el paginador se muestra en la vista pero no me funciona, o se me daña el buscador

Comment: Agrega toda la información pertinente a la pregunta para poder ayudar, desconocemos tu proyecto y tu contexto y el resto del código.

Comment: $city1 = $request->get('city1');
    $arr_city1= explode(' ', $city1);
    $direccion = $request->get('direccion');
    $arr_direccion= explode(' ', $direccion);
    $where = '';
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_city1);$i++){
      $where.='city1 LIKE "%'.$arr_city1[$i].'%" AND ';
    }
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_direccion);$i++){
      $where.='direccion LIKE "%'.$arr_direccion[$i].'%" AND ';
    }
    $where = substr($where,0,strlen($where)-4)." ORDER BY id";
    $clientes = DB::select('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE '.$where);
    return view('index', compact('clientes'));

Comment: eso es lo que tengo en mi controlador, para realizar la búsqueda